# Go-error:value of type int as []int value

Tags: arrays, go, recursion

I am a beginner in programming and in stackoverflow too.

I have to make a recursive function in go that adds the elements of an array and if the length of the array is 0 it returns 0.

```
func Suma(vector []int) int {
    n := len(vector)
    if n == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return Suma(vector[n] + vector[n-1])
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    vector := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    res := Suma(vector)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

It gives me that error but I don't understand it.

> cannot use vector[n] + vector[n - 1] (value of type int) as []int value in argument to Suma

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here is your problem:

The error message you're seeing is because you're trying to pass an int value to the Suma function, which expects a slice of int.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func Suma(vector []int) int {
    n := len(vector)
    if n == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        // You should call Suma recursively with a slice of the vector, excluding the last element.
        // Also, you need to add the current element (vector[n-1]) to the sum.
        return vector[n-1] + Suma(vector[:n-1])
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    vector := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    res := Suma(vector)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```